# How to implement the Boolean function  =  + ′′ + ′ with NAND and NOT gates

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, digital-logic, booleanquery

I have done the problem with AND , OR and NOT gates but cant figure out how to do with NAND and NOT gates.

I dont know how to implement the NAND gate for this boolean expression.

Comment: You can convince yourself of and use the following: `OR(a, b) = NAND(NOT(a), NOT(b))` and `AND(a, b) = NOT(OR(NOT(a), NOT(b)))`

Comment: You don't even need the `NOT` gate. You can build every logic expression with NAND alone. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic

Answer (score 0):

Using   DeMorgan's Laws:

```
    xy    +  x'y'        +  yz
   (xy)'' + (x'y')''     + (yz)''     // all ANDs converted to NOT'd NANDs
  ((xy)'''  (x'y')''')'  + (yz)''     // first OR converted to NAND w/ args NOT'd
 (((xy)'''  (x'y')''')''   (yz)''')'  // second OR converted to NAND w/ args NOT'd
 (((xy)'    (x'y')')''     (yz)')'    // extra NOT's removed
```